# Slack is not sending message_replied subtype event

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I'm using events api but slack doesn't send `message_replied` event when I reply to a message in a thread. All other subtype message events are sent correctly.

Notice the `undefined` subtype in following trace. subtype is set correctly for all other events except replies.

```
type: message --- subtype: undefined
type: message --- subtype: message_changed
type: message --- subtype: undefined
type: message --- subtype: thread_broadcast
type: message --- subtype: message_changed
type: message --- subtype: undefined
type: message --- subtype: message_changed
type: message --- subtype: message_deleted
```